# How to recover AccountId from ECDSA signature in ink!

Tags: ink

In ink! 4.0 `ink::env` crate, it provides `ecdsa_recover` function.
It returns compressed public key `&[u8, 33]` as is explained [here](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/fd0a45d68c8e3b61a5a3ca937b746e1f69a9e6b4/crates/ink/src/env_access.rs#L791).

Assumed that `blake2` is used for hashing.

```
#[ink(message)]
pub fn verify(&self, req: ForwardRequest, signature: [u8; 65]) -> bool {
    let mut message_hash = <ink::env::hash::Blake2x256 as ink::env::hash::HashOutput>::Type::default();
    ink::env::hash_encoded::<ink::env::hash::Blake2x256, _>(&req, &mut message_hash);

    let output = self.env().ecdsa_recover(&signature, &message_hash).expect("Failed to recover");

    let signature_account_id = // How to get AccountId from compressed public key?

    todo!();
}
```

(Above code before todo!() is not confirmed to work)

How can I recover `AccountId` from compressed public key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the AccountId, you need to hash the compressed public key with Blake2x256

I will just update your question - the function used in the question (where the output public key is the output of `ecdsa_recover`) is for ink! version < 4.0.0, ink! v4's `ecdsa_recover` function stores the output public key in the third parameter `output`, see the function [here](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/fn.ecdsa_recover.html).

```
pub fn ecdsa_recover(
    signature: &[u8; 65],
    message_hash: &[u8; 32],
    output: &mut [u8; 33]
) -> Result<()>
```

Then you can hash the output value with Blake and get the AccountId.

Comment: Thank you so much! I try to use Blake for hashing!
I think current implementation compressed public key is output of the `ecdsa_recover` function. https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/4e566173dcaf57f67b3cfc2204d0e5dbe10a7bd2/crates/ink/src/env_access.rs#L791

ink_env crate doc is old I guess, after ink! 4.0, we can check ink::env instead

Comment: yes you're correct, I will update my answer)

Comment: Although code is messy, here's how I could recover AccountId.
https://github.com/shunsukew/verifier/blob/main/contract/lib.rs

And TS side to call verify message
https://github.com/shunsukew/verifier/blob/main/ts/index.ts